# Pandas merge join where key can be null

Tags: pandas

I would like to do a pandas left merge on a key column but only when the key is not null. 
In SQL:

```
select * from tb1l left join tbl2 on tbl1.id=tbl2.id and tbl1.id is not null
```

How can I do in pandas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, SO is not a free code writing service, nor is it a tutorial website.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve] that asks a specific programming question, with a clear sample input/output.  Don't forgot to also include your attempt to solve your own problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
df = (df_tb1l
      .loc[lambda d: d["id"].notnull(), "id"]
      .merge(df_tbl2, on=["id"], how="left"]
      .merge(df_tb1l, on=["id"], how="right"])
```